# Two SurfaceView with Thread - Camera Preview Cannot Resume

Tags: android, multithreading, camera, surfaceview

I am creating an app that shows a moving picture on top of camera preview. And the way I am doing it is adding two SurfaceView, one holding camera preview and one holding my moving picture, in a framelayout inside my main activity. So basically there are three public classes, and one inner thread class inside the moving picture class to control the animation.

It worked fine upon starting the app - camera is previewing and picture is moving. But then **if I pause the activity, by going to home screen or by redirecting into another activity with clicking the picture, and resume, the camera preview would black out.** The wierd part is if I rotate the phone into a different mode (landscape/portrait), thing comes back to normal.

I've read several post about camera not resuming, but the solutions were all about opening camera. I'm pretty much sure my problem is not about the camera instance after examining. And actually if I pause activity by going to home screen, when I resume the camera would appear for a second and then black out.

I've been trying all kinds of things including removing all views from my layout in OnPause() and specifying index number when adding the views. But the only method that kind of got a little progress was when I comment out the canvas lock in the following block. Without the lock, the picture would move randomly, but camera could resume and all. In fact, if I leave out all things about thread and just display a static picture, camera works fine too. So I am sensing something is wrong with my thread here but I couldn't figure out.

Here's the thread's run method:

```
    public void run() {
        Canvas canvas;
        while (isRunning) {         //When setRunning(false) occurs, isRunning is 
            canvas = null;          //set to false and loop ends, stopping thread
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);        //Lock
                        synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                                //Insert methods to modify positions of items in onDraw()
                                animation();
                                postInvalidate();
                            }
            } finally {
                if (canvas != null) {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  //Unlock
                            }
                    }
        }
    }
```

Here's the part starting the thread:

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        setWillNotDraw(false); //Allows us to use invalidate() to call onDraw()

        thread = new BubbleThread(getHolder(), this);   //Start the thread that
        thread.setRunning(true);                        //will make calls to 
        thread.start();                                 //onDraw()
    }
```

Here's the part finishing the thread:

```
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        try {
            thread.setRunning(false);                //Tells thread to stop
        thread.join();                              //Removes thread from mem.
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
```

[UPDATE] main activity code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ... // Declarations

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            /* Adjust app settings */
            ...

            //Load();
        }

        public void Load(){
            /* Try to get the camera */
            Camera c = getCameraInstance();

            /* If the camera was received, create the app */
            if (c != null){
                // Create the parent layout to layer the
                // camera preview and bubble layer
                parentLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
                parentLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                // Create a new camera view and add it to the layout
                cameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, c);
                parentLayout.addView(cameraPreview, 0);

                // Create a new draw view and add it to the layout
                bubbleLayer = new BubbleLayer(this);
                parentLayout.addView(bubbleLayer, 1);

                // Set the layout as the apps content view 
                setContentView(parentLayout);
            }
            /* If the camera was not received, close the app */
            else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Unable to find camera. Closing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                finish();
            }
        }

        /** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
        /** This method is strait from the Android API */
        public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
            Camera c = null;
            try {
                // Attempt to get a Camera instance
                c = Camera.open();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return c;
        }

        /* Override the onPause method so that we 
        * can release the camera when the app is closing.
        */
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            if (cameraPreview != null){
                cameraPreview.onPause();
                cameraPreview = null;
            }
        }

        /* We call Load in our Resume method, because 
        * the app will close if we call it in onCreate
        */
        @Override 
        protected void onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            Load();
        }
    }
```

[/UPDATE]

[UPDATE2] camera preview code:

```
    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        ... // Declarations
        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            this.context = context;
            mCamera = camera;
            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            Size bestSize = getBestSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(),
                    width,height);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            // stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }
            // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
            // reformatting changes here
            // start preview with new settings
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                setCameraDisplayOrientation();
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("CameraView", "Error starting camera preview: "
                    + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the
            // camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("CameraView", "Error setting camera preview: "
                    + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
        }

        /* Find the best size for camera */
        private Size getBestSize(List<Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
            final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
            double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
            if (sizes == null) return null;

            Size bestSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = h;

            // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
            for (Size size : sizes) {
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    bestSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }

            // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
            if (bestSize == null) {
                minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        bestSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                    }
                }
            }
            return bestSize;
        }


        private void setCameraDisplayOrientation() {        
            if (mCamera == null) return;

            Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(0, info);
            WindowManager winManager = (WindowManager)
                        context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        int rotation = winManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
            case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
            case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
        }
        else {  // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        }

    public void onPause() {
        if (mCamera == null) return;
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }    
    }
```

[/UPDATE2]

Another thing I found out was that when I paused the activity, the unlock was seldom executed. Though when it was executed camera still didn't come back, but this behavior seemed wierd to me because the thread.join() was executed so I assume the finally block should have been executed as well.

Sorry I couldn't desribe my question with less words, but please leave any clue you have. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you describe seems to be, that you stop "something" at `onPause` that is started in `onCreate`. If you pause your app and resume it, the `onPause` code runs. If you rotate the screen, the Activity is recreated and `onCreate` runs again. Can you post us the code of your Activity?

Comment: @jboi Thanks a lot for replying! I just posted the activity code. I'm starting all the staff in `onResume` since, according to my understanding, onResume gets called every time `onCreate` is called. I suppose I am stopping the camera in `onPause` by calling  `onPause` from CameraPreview class, which was implemented to stop preview and release camera.

Comment: This part of the code seems to be straigth forward. As `onResume` is called as often as `onPause` (as long as now Exception is thrown) this should be ok. How did you implement the `CameryPreview` class? Is something in there, that does not stop and release before you open the camera again? (Well, I'm now just guessing. I think the best way to find out is to `Log` all your calls and see what is unbalanced)

Comment: @jboi I put `CameraPreview` class in `[UPDATE2][/UPDATE2]`. I didn't think the problem was here because when I left out thread and simply draw static picture, camera preview worked just fine. I've tried logging many places, but the only unbalance I found was in thread class, that the `unlockCanvasAndPost` didn't run most of the time. So whenever paused, the canvas is in locked state. This doesn't make sense to me because `thread.join()` was executed so I assumed `finally` block should have been executed as well, shouldn't it?

Comment: Good question. Is the `isRunning` variable declared as `volatile`? This is needed to let Java recognize a Chang in the value.

Comment: @jboi It wasn't, and I just tried. Adding `volatile` didn't seem to change the situation. My log still showed canvas was in locked state when paused X(

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know exactly what was wrong with my program. But after researching, I found it seemed to be something tricky with SurfaceView's z order not following normal rules. So instead of using two SurfaceViews, one for camera and one for drawing, I switched to using one SurfaceView for both and it works fine now.

But according to my experiments, with either implementation, drawing on screen with camera preview on is anyways a slow implementation because of all the switching between threads. So one should probably try to avoid doing so in the design...

Comment: I think that the **[SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html)** was introduced exactly to resolve this kind of problems. Too bad if you still must support [Gingerbread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#GINGERBREAD_MR1)..

Comment: When the camera is displaying on a surface holder, you get an error when trying to lock it on the `run` method. How did you get around this?